# powershell hashtable dynamic key

Tags: powershell, dynamic, path, key, hashtable

I would like to ask you about dynamic nested keys in hashtables (powershell).
I 've already done some research and I can't find an answer.

```
# I got this hash structure, works fine
$Hashtable                                              = @{}
$Hashtable.Maincategory                             = @{}
$Hashtable.Maincategory.Subcategory                 = @{}
$Hashtable.Maincategory.Subcategory.MyProperty          = @{ 'property' = 'value'}
$Hashtable.Maincategory.Subcategory.MyProperty

Name                           Value
----                           -----
property                       value



# I want dynamic path to my property
$MainAndSubCategory                                                                = [string]'Maincategory.Subcategory'
$Hashtable.$MainAndSubCategory.MyProperty                                               # doesn't work
$Hashtable."$MainAndSubCategory".MyProperty                                         # doesn't work
$Hashtable."$($MainAndSubCategory)".MyProperty                                       # doesn't work
$Hashtable."$(Get-Variable -Name 'MainAndSubCategory' -ValueOnly)".MyProperty           # doesn't work
```

I would appreciate advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to build a string, then execute it using `Invoke-Expression`. Note that the initial `$` character is escaped.

```
$Hashtable                                     = @{}
$Hashtable.Maincategory                        = @{}
$Hashtable.Maincategory.Subcategory            = @{}
$Hashtable.Maincategory.Subcategory.MyProperty = @{ 'property' = 'value'}
$Hashtable.Maincategory.Subcategory.MyProperty

$MainAndSubCategory = 'Maincategory.Subcategory'
Invoke-Expression -Command "`$Hashtable.$MainAndSubCategory.MyProperty"
```

One thing to be careful about is that anything that could set the value of the string would be able to inject unwanted code.

Answer (score 0):

this will work, but I'm not sure, if this is a solution, you are looking for

`$Hashtable.$(($MainAndSubcategory -split '\.')[0]).$(($MainAndSubcategory -split '\.')[1]).myproperty`

It is the same as put maincategory and subcategory keys into the separate variables